# What is the best time complexity possible to find a solution to x^2 + y^2 = m where m can be any natural number?

Tags: algorithm, math, quadratic, number-theory

I have to find a solution to the equation x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = m where m can be any natural number and x,y are integers. This can be done in O(m<sup>1/2</sup>) by using brute force easily. Is there a way I can do this in constant time?

Comment: `x = sqrt(m), y = 0`. Or, if `x` and `y` are supposed to be integral, you probably should have said so :-)

Comment: what is known and unknown? what are x,y? integers > 0 , R , C? If `m` is known and x,y are unknonw then for limited `m` you can use LUT which is `O(1)`

Comment: @Sujay_K and what is unknown?

Comment: A solution or all solutions?

Comment: This question is offtopic here and belongs to a dedicated Math SE site, for instance here http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: m is known and x,y are to be found. @Spektre

Comment: @paxdiablo You meant integer perhaps? I got confused for two minutes thinking about calculus solutions.

Comment: A solution. @Simon

Comment: @luk32, integral as an adjective means (among other definitions) `of or denoted by an integer`, the *noun* integral would indeed be calculus but then I would have written "*an* integral". Now deactivating "PITA pedant" mode :-)

Comment: @walther mathoverflow is research-level mathematics. This asker wants [math.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [math.se]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you can do it any better than `O(sqrt(m))` for an arbitrary `m` but that's pretty damn good , much better than linear time :-)

The approach is to start `x` and `y` at opposite ends of the solution space and either increment the low end or decrement the high end, depending on whether the result is too low or too high (obviously if the result is perfect, return the values):

```
def solveForM(m):
    set lo to 0
    set hi to sqrt(m), rounded up.
    while lo < hi:
        testVal = lo * lo + hi * hi
        if testVal == m:
            return (lo, hi)
        if testVal > m:
            hi = hi - 1
        else lo = lo + 1
    return "No solution"
```

---

If `m` can be limited somehow, you could achieve `O(1)` by use of a lookup table (many optimisations come down to trading space for time), such as:

```
 0 ->  0, 0
 1 ->  0, 1
 2 ->  1, 1
       No solution for 3
 4 ->  0, 2
 5 ->  1, 2
       No solution for 6, 7
 8 ->  2, 2
 9 ->  0, 3
10 ->  1, 3
       No solution for 11, 12
13 ->  2, 3
... and so on.
```

A table like this can be generated with a small program along the lines of (Python 3):

```
for hi in range(1001):
    for lo in range(1001):
        m = lo * lo + hi * hi
        print("%5d -> %d, %d"%(m, lo, hi))
```

You have to sort (and possibly remove duplicates) afterwards to create a fast look-up table but the performance is okay with the generation of an unsorted list taking fifteen seconds for all `m` up to two million.

In any case, this is only *run* once, after which you would place the table into code where the time expense is incurred at compile time.

Comment: m can be as large as 10^10

Comment: You can definitely do better: for prime `m`, there's an algorithm based on Fermat's descent method that will give a solution in polynomial time in `log(m)`. And for non-prime `m`, it's possible to build all solutions from the solutions for prime `m`. So for large composite `m`, the bottleneck essentially comes down to the time to factorise `m`. For a Python solution for prime inputs, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/5883/117283

Comment: @MBo `set hi to sqrt(m), rounded up` is possibly the problem I am using `hi=sqrt(m)+1` which is fine

Comment: @MBo, assuming you meant in the lookup table (where that exact text is), it's not so much a rounding error as it is faulty manual calculations on my part. I probably should have created the table with some code rather than relying on faulty wetware :-) Fixed now.